# Leading colons and whitespaces in Ex commands

Tags: ex-command, posix

Apparently, multiple colons are simply ignored when executing Ex commands. For example,

```
:set number!
:::set number!
: :  :set number!
```

all toggle line numbers. Is this really a consolidated rule? Where is it documentated?
I tried `:helpgrep ::` and `:help ::` but did not find anything relevant.

I came to this question after many times having copied Ex commands such as `:set number!`
and pasted to Vim's command line with <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>CTRL+R</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>, so that
the resulting command line had a double colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the leading colons and blanks are ignored. It is documented in the [Command Line Parsing section of the POSIX specification of Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_03).

> Command-line parsing shall be done in the following steps. For each step, characters
> already evaluated shall be ignored; that is, the phrase "leading character" refers to
> the next character that has not yet been evaluated.
>
> 1. Leading <colon> characters shall be skipped.
> 2. Leading <blank> characters shall be skipped.

Also, down below the [informative section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_18_08) reiterates it:

> Historically, ex permitted a single extra <colon> as a leading command character; for example,
> **:g/pattern/:p** was a valid command. POSIX.1-2017 generalizes this to require that any number of
> leading <colon> characters be stripped.